# How to streamline repetitive HTML in GMap locations Array?

Tags: html, arrays, infowindow

I'm trying to tighten up some repetitive HTML in a Google Map (v3 API).

- The map contains 50 markers.
- Each marker has a styled infoWindow.
- Each infoWindow includes HTML that denotes both text and an image.
- The text for each infoWindow is the same but the image is unique.

I would like to put the text HTML into a single variable, then use it to replace the  repeated strings in the code.

This is how the infoWindows are presented:

```
var locations = [
[39.11009, -120.03169, '<same text html><unique image html>'],
[37.77493, -122.41942, '<same text html><unique image html>'],
[48.85320, -119.30206, '<same text html><unique image html>'],
[48.77734, -121.81320, '<same text html><unique image html>']
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable containing the html string common to each array [], then use it to replace the common strings. The proper syntax looks like this:

```
var Links ='<div class="photo"><a href="whatever.com/">Shop Here</a> | <a href="whatever.com/">Shop There</a></div>';
var locations = [
[39.19, -12.9, Links + '<img width="300" height="239" src="images/img01.jpg"/>'],
[37.73, -12.4, Links + '<img width="300" height="239" src="images/img02.jpg"/>'],
[48.82, -12.3, Links + '<img width="300" height="239" src="images/img03.jpg"/>'],
[48.74, -12.8, Links + '<img width="300" height="239" src="images/img04.jpg"/>'],
[39.37, -12.7, Links + '<img width="300" height="239" src="images/img05.jpg"/>']
];
```